# Signed Message Using EIP712 Specification Does Not Return Correct Address

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I sign the typed data value with types data structure for domain using the EIP-712 specification by study and following https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/ and in my solidity code, I followed the method used both on the Metamask blog here https://medium.com/metamask/eip712-is-coming-what-to-expect-and-how-to-use-it-bb92fd1a7a26 and on the Compound Contract which is a live project, although the Compound Contract uses solidity version 0.5 and I am trying to achieve this using 0.7 which has major breaking changes, I have been careful to make appropriate changes.

Below is my Javascript code:

```
const signPayment = (recipient, amount, nonce, verifyingContract) => {
    const domain = {
        name: "Micro Payment",
        version: "1.0",
        chainId: chainId,
        verifyingContract: verifyingContract,
    };

    const types = {
        Cheque: [
            { name: "recipient", type: "address"},
            { name: "amount", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
        ]
    };

    const value = {
        recipient: recipient,
        amount: amount,
        nonce: nonce,
    };

    signer._signTypedData(domain, types, value)
        .then((signature) => {
            $('[name=signature]').val(signature);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

I am on Rinkeby and likewise deployed the solidity code below on Remix to the Rinkeby network.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >0.6.99 <0.8.0;
pragma abicoder v2;

contract ReceiverPays {

address public _verifyingContract;

uint constant chainId = 4;

bytes32 public sigR;

bytes32 public sigS;

uint8  public sigV;

constructor() {
    _verifyingContract = address(this);
}

struct Cheque {
    address recipient;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 nonce;
    address verifyingContract;
}

/// @notice The EIP-712 typehash for the contract's domain
bytes32 public constant DOMAIN_TYPEHASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)"));

/// @notice The EIP-712 typehash for the delegation struct used by the contract
bytes32 public constant CHEQUE_TYPEHASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Cheque(address recipient,uint256 amount,uint256 nonce,address verifyingContract)"));

function claimPayment(address recipient, uint256 _amount,uint256 _nonce,bytes memory _signature) public returns (address payer) {

    bytes32 domainSeparator = keccak256(
        abi.encode(
            DOMAIN_TYPEHASH,
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                bytes("Micro Payment"),bytes("1.0"),chainId,address(this)
            ))
        )
    );

    bytes32 structHash = keccak256(abi.encode(CHEQUE_TYPEHASH, recipient, _amount, _nonce));
    bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", domainSeparator, structHash));

    (sigR, sigS, sigV) = splitSignature(_signature);

    return ecrecover(digest, sigV, sigR, sigS);
}

function splitSignature(bytes memory sig) public pure returns (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v)
{
    require(sig.length == 65, "invalid signature length");

    assembly {
    /*
    First 32 bytes stores the length of the signature

    add(sig, 32) = pointer of sig + 32
    effectively, skips first 32 bytes of signature

    mload(p) loads next 32 bytes starting at the memory address p into memory
    */

    // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix
        r := mload(add(sig, 32))
    // second 32 bytes
        s := mload(add(sig, 64))
    // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes)
        v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
    }

    return (r, s, v);
}

}
```

I can't say for sure where exactly, I am getting this wrong. I would really appreciate all the help I can get!